# Action on UILabel in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I have created some set of labels programmatically to display on the screen and i want after clicking on label some action should perform.

Please don't suggest me about UIButton. I want to do it for UILabel. After clicking on the label another detail view should appear.

Please help me to solve this problem without using Inteface Builder.

Comment: What's wrong with UIButton? I think a transparent UIbutton has nothing different with what you want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Finally i came up with the solution and i got the result

```
 [titleLbl setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelButton:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [titleLbl addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    [tapGestureRecognizer release];
```

Answer (score 4):

make `IBoutlet` of your label,
implement `touchesBegin` in your controller, pull out the `CGPoint` - touchCoordinate, check

```
CGRectContainsPoint(label.frame,touchCoordinate)
{
//you got the touch action on your label
}
```

Comment: set your label's tag while creating it: assume you have set tag:199 . then, you can fetch label whenever you require by UILabel *label = [self.view viewWithTag:199];

Comment: you can fetch the label's object without IBOutlet using above. I hope it will help..

Comment: i want to do action after clicking on the label field so how should i use tag and when to use it

Comment: as for action, you can write UILabel *label = [self.view viewWithTag:199]; CGRectContainsPoint(label.frame,touchCoordinate)
{
//you got the touch action on your label here you may make a function call for your action.
}

Comment: you can set tag to your label from interface builder after selecting the label and moving on to property window and entering a value in TAG field

Comment: i am creating labels programmatically

Comment: so u can set label.tag = 199; before adding as subview. beyond that.. i can only say u first learn Objective-C before jumping into coding. I can't give you programming lessons here..!!

Answer (score 3):

In

```
  -(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
 .......
 .......
 CGPoint touch;//Touch Location

if(CGRectContainsPoint([objectOfLable frame], [touch locationInView:self.view ]) )
{
  Do What you Want
}

}
```

Try This